# My sftp jailed user can't see directories below the ChrootDirectory

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp

I am trying to jail user. I have got these directories:

```
var/www (root:www-data, 755)         
var/www/web1 (webmaster:www-data, 755)         
var/www/web2 (webmaster:www-data, 755)
```

In my ssh_config I have got:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

Match User webmaster
  ChrootDirectory /var/www
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

The user can enter the system with the credentials. Also, the user can navigate to var/www, but he cannot access web1 or web2. I don't know why because "webmaster" is the owner of web1 and web2.

Thank you very much. I think that the permissions have been set correctly but I am not an expert in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see in your configuration is that all folders in tree, to where you want to jail user, must be owned (user and group) by `root`.

In your case it should be:

```
 /var/www (root:root, 755)
```

Comment: If my answer helped you to the solution, could you mark it as approved? TY

Answer (score 0):

Here's my config, hope it helps.

```
/var/www (root:root, 755)
/var/www/user1 (user1:sftpusers, 755)
/var/www/user2 (user2:sftpusers, 755)
```

And my sshd_config:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

Match Group sftpusers
  ChrootDirectory /var/www/%u
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
```